# Expected value of first and second moment

Tags: probability

I have the following

- Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$, $Y_1, Y_2, \ldots, Y_n$ and $W_1, W_2, \ldots, W_n$ be independent, real-valued random variables
- Suppose that $X_n$ are i.i.d. with 
  $$E\left[X_n\right]=0,\quad\quad E\left[X_n^2\right]=1$$
- Suppose that $Y_n$ only are indpendent, but not identical, with: 
  $$E\left[Y_n\right]=0,\quad\quad E\left[Y_n^2\right]=n^2$$
- Suppose that $W_n\sim\text{Bernoulli}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$ with
  $$P(W_n=0)=1-\frac{1}{n^2},\quad P(W_n=1)=\frac{1}{n^2}$$
- Define
  $$Z_n=X_n+W_nY_n$$

---

I have to find $E\left[Z_n\right]$ 
$$
E\left[Z_n\right]=E\left[X_n+W_nY_n\right]
  =E\left[X_n\right]+E\left[W_n\right]E\left[Y_n\right] 
  =0+E\left[W_n\right]\cdot 0 
  =0
$$

and $E\left[Z_n^2\right]$:
$$
  E\left[Z_n^2\right]=E\left[\left(X_n+W_nY_n\right)^2\right]=E\left[X_n^2\right]+E\left[W_n^2\right]E\left[Y_n^2\right]+2E\left[X_n\right]E\left[Y_n\right]E\left[W_n\right]
$$
$$
  =1+E\left[W_n^2\right]n^2+2\cdot 0\cdot 0\cdot E\left[W_n\right]=1+\frac{1}{n^2}n^2=2
$$

I am not sure whether this is possible, when $Y_n$ only is indpendent, but not also identical. Any help regarding this, will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is a bit strange: if $\mathbb E[X_n] = 0$, and $\mathbb E[X_n^2] = 0$, then $X_n$ is just $0$ with probability $1$. This is because $\sigma^2 = \mathbb E[X_n^2] - (\mathbb E[X_n])^2 = 0$, so having a variance of $0$ implies $X_n$ is just a constant, and that constant must specifically be $0$. It doesn't break the problem or anything, but it's just... strange.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery - sorry, my mistake - I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crux of your question is: are your steps OK when we only have independence, or was identical distribution required anywhere? The answer to that is: $\fbox{no, you're fine.}$

The big algebraic rule that you applied several times is the expression $\mathbb E[U V] = \mathbb E[U] \mathbb E[V]$ for various random variables $U$, $V$. This applies so long as $U, V$ are independent of one another (and everything in your problem statement is independent of everything else). Whether they are identically distributed is irrelevant.

If it makes you any more comfortable with it, you're making a statement *for each value of $n$*, and you're showing that the expectation happens to be the same *for every possible value of $n$*.